# SQL Server : how to select top 2 records of the same group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I have a problem where I need to get the top 2 records in a group determined by 2 columns `Code` and `Period`, that will then be inserted to another table.

Here is a sample table:

```
Code  |  Period  |  Dept  | DeptWorkPartSum
001      2013-11    D1      53
001      2013-11    D2      33
001      2013-11    D3      12
002      2013-11    D2      30
002      2013-11    D4      28
002      2013-11    D5      15
002      2013-12    D2      100
```

And what I want to get out of it is:

```
Code  |  Period  |  Dept  | DeptWorkPartSum
001      2013-11    D1      53
001      2013-11    D2      33
002      2013-11    D2      30
002      2013-11    D4      28
002      2013-12    D2      100
```

It is probably a very simple solution but I can't figure it out at the moment.

Comment: Determined by three columns? But then your desired result is wrong since the `Dept` is different for all three.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, got a bit confused because of a previous query which calculated `DeptWorkPartSum` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is using a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER` ranking function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Code,Period,Dept,DeptWorkPartSum,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code,Period, Dept
                                   ORDER BY DeptWorkPartSum)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT Code,Period,Dept,DeptWorkPartSum
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 2
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33944/2/0)</kbd>

However, your desired result seems to be incorrect since `Dept` is different for all three codes.

Maybe you don't want to group by `Dept` but order by it, then the result is correct:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Code,Period,Dept,DeptWorkPartSum,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code,Period
                                   ORDER BY Dept, DeptWorkPartSum)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT Code,Period,Dept,DeptWorkPartSum
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 2
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33944/5/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Code, Period, Dept, DeptWorkPartSum
FROM (
  SELECT Code, Period, Dept, DeptWorkPartSum
    ,ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Code, Period, Dept ORDER BY DeptWorkPartSum DESC) r
  FROM table) q
WHERE r <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:


with cte as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Code,Period,Dept order by Code) as rn from table
)

select Code,Period,Dept,DeptWorkPartSum from cte where rn<=2
```

## [fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33944/7)